# how to get days of current week in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to extract the days of current week from my date in database and place them into this chart [image]
but I don't know how to find what day is for example this day  `2016-05-05`

Comment: Can you share the db structure?

Comment: What's your expected out put and what is your data?

Comment: What do you mean by db Stracture

Comment: We will not do homework /work assignment for you! get into some reading about SQL and its field types

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to understand how to ask good questions.

Comment: Its not my homework, if cant answer it dont comment

Comment: What information do you need ask me to provide you @Peter , I think its so clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to DAYOFWEEK() is `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`
For example `DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%a')` The output can be

> sun,Sat

Answer (score 4):

you can use `DAYOFWEEK()` function

> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

then you can gruop your sales BY DAYOFWEEK(...)

but if you're also trying to create a pivot table based on the seller name then this is another question

Comment: Thanks This is my question Answer @arilia